# Openssl error message: Could not open file or uri for loading private key from -inkey file from secure.xxxxxxxx.com_key.txt: No such file or directory

Tags: openssl

try to use a command I use last year to upload my certificate on microsoft azue website but I get this error message: Could not open file or uri for loading private key from -inkey file from secure.xxxxxxx.com_key.txt: No such file or directory

I put both file secure_xxxxxxx_com.crt and secure_xxxxxxx_com.ca-bundle in the directory where I run the command